ASP.NET MVC Single Page App - Maintaining '#' URL in Contact Form POST
I have a single-page application with a contact form in a component view on the Index action.
How can I redirect to localhost:5001/#contact after the form is submitted instead of returning to the Index action?
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(Contact model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.error = "An error occurred! Please try again.";
            return View(model);
        }

        ViewBag.success = "Your message was sent :D";

        return View(model);
    }

I tried [Route("/#{index}")] but it's not working.

This question is similar to: ASP.Net MVC RedirectToAction with anchor. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can do a return Redirect(urlToRedirectTo)
You can refer to Microsoft's .NET Documentation
